# MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification is called immediately

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to play video with the following code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1,1));

self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.blablabla.org/app/video/v5_seq8_v2_360p.mp4"]];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didFinishPlayback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.player.moviePlayer];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.player];

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[self.player.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.player.moviePlayer play];
```

The `sel.player` closes and `didFinishPlayback:` method is called instantly. I retrieve the error from the notification like this:

```
NSLog(@"Error %@", notification.userInfo[@"error"]);
```

and it looks like the following:

```
Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11850 "Operation Stopped"
```

but when i open the url in a browser then the video starts playing without any problems. What can be the cause of this error? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure why, but with remote url's I realized in a past project that you need to add the observer without object as reference.... If you ask me why, I am not sure.
Try adding the observer with nil as object...

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

If the video plays on your desktop machine, but not iOS (either in-app or in Safari), it's most likely because the HTTP server does not support [byte-range requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#range-request-header). If the HTTP server does not support byte-range requests, iOS will not play the video. This differs from Safari on OS X, which plays the video regardless.

From the [Safari Web Content Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW6):

> HTTP servers hosting media files for iOS must support byte-range
>   requests, which iOS uses to perform random access in media playback.
>   (Byte-range support is also known as content-range or partial-range
>   support.) Most, but not all, HTTP 1.1 servers already support
>   byte-range requests.

Also, the HTTP server must provide a valid `Content-Type` header (the URL above also enumerates the valid MIME types). iOS will not play the video if the MIME type is invalid or missing.

Answer (score -1):

Try insert this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self.player
                                                name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object: self.player.moviePlayer];
```

before

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didFinishPlayback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.player.moviePlayer];
```

Comment: http://josebolanos.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/dismissing-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-the-right-way/

Comment: i want help you only. i found for you the example.

Comment: i tried it already. unfortunately it has nothing to do with my issue

Comment: did you try set up property:
    self.player.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    self.player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming; ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314299/how-to-config-my-server-to-providing-the-video-file-play-with-mpmovieplayerviewc

Comment: thank you for your help. i've tried all that and i've seen all the related SO questions. nothing works. it's something with video, not player