# iOS- MPMoviePlayerController uable to play video from remote URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to play video from remote URL. But it is not working. My code is :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"start playing");

    NSURL *nsURL= [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://my_server_path:8080/content-service/v1/video/12/RGl1Nm1ib1VLMitFUmM5bEZzYVpxVGllM2RrWUw3Y09yMzdVZ0pzYlEvYjNaYUI5bEQvZERhTUhNTjBOaW5lY1hqYlZSRUM5anAvL3FsUTA2NzEwN2NMM2dnUnkxR0s4QUVyMnV2MlBLMjA9?thumb=false"];

    videoPlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                    initWithContentURL:nsURL];

    [videoPlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    videoPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    videoPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;//MPMovieSourceTypeFile/MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown ;
    [self.view addSubview:videoPlayer.view];
    [videoPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [videoPlayer play];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                      selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                          name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                        object:videoPlayer];

    videoPlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {

    NSError *error = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Did finish with error: %@", error);
    }
}
```

**I am getting this message**

> Did finish with error: Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain
>   Code=-11850 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo=0x15e77b20
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped}

When I copy/paste my video URL in a browser it downloads successfully (even not buffers in browser) and after finished download it plays fine in laptop. I am frustrated, PLEASE HELP, any suggestion will be great, Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using a URL other than your local server?

Comment: "When I copy/paste my video URL in a browser it downloads successfully (even not buffers in browser) and after finished download it plays fine in laptop" - this is because it's from your computer, not from a remote server. Your code appears fine.

Comment: DOES IT RUN ON SIMULATOR?

Comment: Let me check out, once I have done I will share results with you.

Comment: Does video play  it on your simulator?

Comment: no same issue, video does not play even in simulator.

Comment: Hi! Have you eventually solved the issue? I am struggling with the very same problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ Lunatic999, Yeah I found what was the problme for me : My HTTP server does not support byte-range requests. **Please must ensure your HTTP server support byter -range requests.** See this link for more information. **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250368/mpmovieplayerplaybackdidfinishnotification-is-called-immediately/26725402#26725402**

Comment: That is my problem too :) my server doesn't support byte-range. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If video is not playing on device, your HTTP server does not support byte-range requests.

> HTTP servers hosting media files for iOS must support byte-range
>   requests, which iOS uses to perform random access in media playback.
>   (Byte-range support is also known as content-range or partial-range
>   support.) Most, but not all, HTTP 1.1 servers already support
>   byte-range requests.

[Source From Safari Web Service Content](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW6)

[Source From Byte-Range Request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#range-request-header)

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314299/how-to-config-my-server-to-providing-the-video-file-play-with-mpmovieplayerviewc)

Comment: @ user3182143, how to know servers already support byte-range(content-range or partial-range ) requests  OR NOT ??

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

where fileURL is URL of video on server

```
    MPMoviePlayerViewController* tmpMoviePlayViewController=[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

    if (tmpMoviePlayViewController) {
        tmpMoviePlayViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:tmpMoviePlayViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        [tmpMoviePlayViewController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
//        tmpMoviePlayViewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
        tmpMoviePlayViewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
        [tmpMoviePlayViewController.moviePlayer play];

    }
```

Comment: Hi all, I run this command on termianl and got this response :  curl -I my_server_path_/content-service/v1/video...........
RESULT :

**HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-XX--
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="12345"
Content-Type: video/mp4
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 25 Feb 2016 17:58:46 GMT**

Answer (score 0):

Replace your url in this code with fileUrl

```
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpvc = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] init];
    mpvc.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    [mpvc.moviePlayer setContentURL:fileURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpvc];
```